# The Google Script Im using updates my sheet but old data is sometimes left in the sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, data-import

I'm using the script below as a substitute for ImportRange.  The problem I am having now is that it doesn't replace the sheet each day off the trigger I have set in the google script.  There is old data that sometimes get left in the sheet.   If there a way to make it Replace sheet each day?

If someone has a suggestion that would be great!

```
var sourceSpreadsheetID = "TO UPDATE";
var sourceWorksheetName = "TO UPDATE";
var targetSpreadsheetID = "TO UPDATE";
var targetWorksheetName = "TO UPDATE";

function importData() {
var thisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetID);
var thisWorksheet = thisSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceWorksheetName);
var thisData = thisWorksheet.getDataRange();
//Uncomment line 11 below and comment out line 9 if you want to sync a named range. Replace "teamBugs" with your named range.
//var thisData = thisSpreadsheet.getRangeByName("teamBugs");


var toSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetSpreadsheetID);
var toWorksheet = toSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetWorksheetName);
var toRange = toWorksheet.getRange(1, 1, thisData.getNumRows(), thisData.getNumColumns())
toRange.setValues(thisData.getValues()); 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).

Comment: Do you mean the trigger doesn't run or that the sheet still has data from the previous run you'd like to remove?

Comment: Hi yes! But coopers solution below worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var sourceSpreadsheetID = "TO UPDATE";
var sourceWorksheetName = "TO UPDATE";
var targetSpreadsheetID = "TO UPDATE";
var targetWorksheetName = "TO UPDATE";

function importData() {
  var thisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetID);
  var thisWorksheet = thisSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceWorksheetName);
  var thisData = thisWorksheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var toSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetSpreadsheetID);
  var toWorksheet = toSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetWorksheetName);
  toWorksheet.clearContents();
  toWorksheet.getRange(1, 1, thisData.length, thisData[0].length).setValues(thisData); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will try!

Comment: HI THIS WORKED THANK YOU FOR THE HELP!